# Error on Python type conversion

Tags: python-2.7

I tried the example on the website for type conversion that gave the result '1' and I got the result below (in Python 2.7). I don't understand what's happening. What is causing the error?

```
str(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interactive input", line 1, in module
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: can't replicate this

Comment: You probably did `str = <some string>` earlier in this session.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably used `str` as a variable. Hence, you are getting that error.

```
>>> str = ''
>>> str(1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    str(1)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

[`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) is a built-in class and you are simply overriding it by using it a as a user defined variable.

You can restart your shell or simply use `del str` to remove the variable definition (as suggested by [@Ken Y-N](https://stackoverflow.com/u/1270789/)).

```
>>> del str
>>> str(1)
'1'
```